# How to acess variable value from one class to another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access a string from one class to another. I have used the property method as follows -

```
Myclass.cs

public class MyClass
{
    private string _user;
    public string user
    { get { return this._user; } set { this._user = value; } }

}

consumption.aspx.cs
```

I am assigning the value to user in a function

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.user = "abc"
```

Now when I try to use this value in my another function which is called after this value is assigned

```
RawDal.cs

MyClass m = new MyClass();
string x = m.user;
```

I get empty value... How to do it?

Comment: You need to use the same instance of `m`... or you could make `User` static.

Comment: You are creating two separate instances of `MyClass`. If you want to persist `user` try using `Singleton`

Comment: Once you create another instance of the MyClass, it is initialized from scratch therefore you cannot access whatever you did previously with the instance of that class anywhere else. You have go for session(if asp.net) or Singleton as said by @wudzik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the same instance.  Try

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _user;
    public string user
    { get { return this._user; } set { this._user = value; } }

}

public string YourFunction()
{
   MyClass m = new MyClass();
   m.user = "abc"
   return m.user;

}
```

If all you want to return is a string try something like

```
string x = YourFunction();
```

Answer (score 13):

As already mentioned in the comments you are creating two separate instances of `MyClass` which results simplified in something like:

```
int a;
a = 3;
int b;
Console.WriteLine("a: " + b); //<-- here it should be obvious why b is not 3
```

You can work around this in 3 ways:

1) Use the same instance of `MyClass` for the second call, but in this case you need to be in the same scope or pass the instance on to the new scope.

2) Make the property/member static:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string User { get; set; } //the "static" is the important keyword, I just used the alternative property declaration to keep it shorter
}
```

Then you can access the same `User` value everywhere via `MyClass.User`.

3) Use a singleton:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass instance = null;
    public static MyClass Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
                instance = new MyClass();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access it via `MyClass.Instance.User`.

There are possibly some more solutions, but these are the common ones.

Comment: Will I get the same result with `MyClass.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance.User` ?

Comment: @T.Todua No, as you can't access static properties via an instance. So `MyClass.Instance.Instance` would already not compile with `Member 'UserQuery.MyClass.Instance' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.