# Passing values into private class via { get; }

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am fairly new to the MVVM design pattern and integrated one yesterday in my program with the help of a fellow user here. However, I can't seem to get the values of the variables into another class via the `{ get; }` function. I tried fixing this for quiet some time now and this is my last resort. This is just the script integrated in a wpf form, but the error is here, so I just pasted the code I thought to be neccesary.

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ServerNames { get; }
            = new string[] { "s1", "s2" };

    public string SSN { get; set; }
            = "s1";

    public string APort { get; set; }
            = "9999";

    public string FPort { get; set; }
            = "9991";

    public string HostName { get; set; }
            = "localhost";
}


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Now, my thought would be to get the values of the viewmodel by just using `{ get; }`

```cs
private class Server
{
    public string HostName { get; }
    public string APort { get; }
    public string FPort { get; }
    public string SSN { get; }
}
```

But this would just leave the 4 variables with a NULL value instead of getting the data from the view model.
How can I get the values of the variables from the view model for further usage into my private class called "Server"?

EDIT:
The server class is initiated later:

```cs
private void WPFLoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        HAServerConnection aConnection =
            new HAServerConnection(server.HostName, UInt16.Parse(server.APort), new HACalls(), new HErrors());
```

Comment: What you have now are four read-only properties that are not initialized to some value other than `null`. You may make them settable (by `{ get; set; }`) and assign some values, or you add a constructor to the Server class that initializes them.

Comment: @Clemens I just want to get the default values from ViewModel, not actually set some new ones, so I didn't use `{ get; set; }` but only `{ get; }`. Is it possible to get the default values this way?

Comment: The view model is a different class. How is it related to the Server class?

Comment: You have to explain us how `Server` is used and how viewmodel will interact with it. Maybe default values should go into `Server` and viewmodel will take them from there. Maybe instance of `Server` will be created by viewmodel, then your approach is fine, you just have to set `Server` properties during construction. Maybe something else..

Comment: It isn't. It's only there to be a collecting point for a few values that it should get from the ViewModel. I thought it was possible to use the `{ get; }` function independent of classes. Is there another way to get the values to the Server class?

Comment: Why is `Server` a private class? How many instance are you creating of `Server`? And why would it get values from the view model unless you actually set the properties somwhere? This makes no sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to acess variable value from one class to another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18357292/1997232) (trollface)

Comment: Did an edit, hope this clears things up a bit. I am creating one instance of Server and the view model values are bound to input from the mentioned wpf form.

Comment: So how is the `Server` instance supposed to get its values if you don't set the properties...?

Comment: @mm8 Im sorry, I don't get what you mean. I declared default values in ViewModel and used the `{ set; }` accessor.

Comment: @MatthiasG.: Why would this set the properties of the `Server` class...?

Comment: @mm8 What happened to the answer? I was just applying it for my situation...

Comment: @MatthiasG.: It was downvoted by people who apparently didn't understand your question (?) but I've undeleted it now. I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the values of the properties will be `null` until you actually set them to some values. You don't seem to be doing this somewhere in your code, and there is no other piece of code that will do it for you.

You could either add setters to the properties and set them when you initialize the `Server`:

```
Server server = new Server() { HostName = viewModel.HostName, APort = viewModel.Aport };
```

Or you could define a constructor that accepts some values and set the properties:

```
private class Server
{
    public Server(string hostName, string aPort, string fPort, string sSN)
    {
        HostName = hostName;
        APort = aPort;
        FPort = fPort;
        SSN = sSN;
    }

    public string HostName { get; }
    public string APort { get; }
    public string FPort { get; }
    public string SSN { get; }
}
```

You will still need to get the actual values from somewhere when you initialize the class, like for example from the view model.